# Python sorting by mask

Tags: python, sorting, text

I have some text:

```
228;u;Ali;
129;cr;Daan;
730;c;Arton;
466;cr;Frynk;
314;c;Katuhkay;
9822;c;Kinberley;
```

i want to write this text to file, but i want to write only lines with symbols ';cr;'

Comment: What do you mean that you have some text? As a list? As a string? As an input file?

Comment: Do you want to sort, write a file or extract text?

Comment: As an input file, extract items.

Comment: You don't want to sort (which implied reordering). You want to select. Search each line for a match, and write to file of it does.

Comment: What if I enter my name as "Smith;cr;John"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("input.csv", "r") as inp, open("output","w") as out:
    inpList = inp.read().split()
    out.write('\n'.join(el for el in inpList if ';cr;' in el))
```

If you wish to read data from the web, use the following:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
inp = urlopen("<URL>")
with open("output","w") as out:
    inpList = inp.read().split()
    out.write('\n'.join(el for el in inpList if ';cr;' in el))
```

`read()` reads the entire file at once. `split()` splits it into a list delimited by white spaces.

```
read(...)
    read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.

    If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
```

For writing to a file, `'\n'.join([elem1,...])` creates a string from all the inpList elements containing ';cr;'. This string is passed to `write(str)` which prints the string to the output file.

Comment: I'm reading just csv file

Comment: The `[]` inside `join()` are redundant.

Comment: In a way yes, but cProfile shows I can reduce a couple of function calls to <genexpr> by writing [].

Comment: @GermanShaich - Sorry, was a typo. fixed.

Comment: When i do this with local file - it's work,but when i try to do with file from internet it's fail(

Comment: @sidi <genexpr> are useful because they do lazy evaluation . For a large life the `list comprehension` will eat lots of memory, coz it generates all the elements first.

Comment: @GermanShaich - Are you trying to read data from the web? You need to use `urllib2` library. See my updated answer.

Comment: If I check the contents of input.txt in the loop as to make sure that after reading it nullable?

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
with open("input.txt") as f,open("output.txt","w") as f2:
    for line in f:                #iterate over each line of input.txt
        if ";cr;" in line:        #if ';cr;' is found
            f2.write(line+'\n')      #then write that line to "output.txt"
```

In python you can easily check for a substring using `in`:

```
In [167]: "f" in "qwertyferty"
Out[167]: True

In [168]: "z" in "qwertyferty"
Out[168]: False
```

Comment: When i do this with local file - it's work,but when i try to do with file from internet it's fail(